# MySql: What is the best data type for columns that will include both whole numbers and decimals?

Tags: mysql

Within a table I have multiple columns with ranging values that include both decimals and whole numbers.  What is the best data type for such a column?  Thanks

Comment: Take a look a decimal  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: Thanks.  I had read that page already.  To be more specific, the column could be empty, a whole number or a decimal with two digits to the right.  If is there an option so that the whole numbers won't include a decimal and the decimal numbers will?

Comment: use: DESC YourTableName; so you get this information for any field in this table. Or if you want to create you can only use CHAR ot VARCHAR datatye but you can store anything in it with no check

Comment: With Varchar will I still be able to search efficiently using a numeric value range?

Comment: Dont store number in VARCHAR

Comment: How can values from the same information domain be sometimes decimals and sometimes whole numbers?  This amounts (it would seem) to an assertion that 2 != 2.00, and I'm not sure how that's possible, assuming these two different kinds (?) of values actually belong together in a single column.